# How do I link a WPF app to a Telerik Report?

Tags: wpf, telerik-reporting

I created a Report Library with a report.

I created a WPF App.
I  added a Report Viewer to the WPF App & pointed it to the report.

How do I link everything together?
The data within the WPF App needs to be in the report.

**My Solution:**
I added a “data” DLL and dded a reference to the data DLL to both the report & the WPF App.
When I run the program:

`instance not found`

OK, that makes sense since there’s no link.

After the WPF App instantiates the data, how is this instance linked to the report?

Comment: See how your question changes the context from "How do I" to "How is this". Be specific and read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Key idea:
Within the Report's code behind,
`protected override void OnNeedDataSource(object sender, System.EventArgs e)`

In the constructor
`Report.DataSource = null;`
// "At runtime Report.NeedDataSource event is raised only when the report has no data source set"

Pass the data from the App to the Report as a parameter.
// This is a work in progress...